# How can I make directory & put image in the directory?

Tags: python

How can I make directory & put image in the directory?
I wrote the following code in `data.py`:

```
import os
import cv2
import argparse
import numpy as np
import math

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
parser.add_argument('input_dir' ,help='input directory')
parser.add_argument('output_dir' ,help='out directory')

args = parser.parse_args()

def find_all_files(directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):

        for file in files:
            p=os.path.join(root, file)
            p=p.split("/")[len(p.split("/"))-2]
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(p)

            yield os.path.join(root, file)

dirname=args.output_dir
if not os.path.exists(dirname):
    os.mkdir(dirname)


folder_img = find_all_files(args.input_dir)
im =cv2.imread(folder_img)
cv2.imwrite(args.output_dir ,im)
```

Now when I run command `python data.py ./photo ./copy_photo`, find a writer for the specified extension in function `imwrite` error happens. I want to make a directory `copy_photo` and put images made by this code in the directory. The `copy_photo` folder is made, so what is wrong in my code? How should I fix this? Am I wrong to write the way of putting images in the `copy_photo` folder?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the precise traceback you get from Python. Your problem description isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

[`cv2.imread()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#Mat%20imread(const%20String&%20filename,%20int%20flags)) accepts a single file name, but you are calling it with a (generator returning a) list of files.

Try this:

```
def find_all_files(directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):

        for file in files:
            # Comment out dead code
            '''
            p=os.path.join(root, file)
            p=p.split("/")[len(p.split("/"))-2]
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(p)
            '''

            # Changed this to return a tuple
            yield root, file

for dirname, imagefile in find_all_files(args.input_dir):
    im =cv2.imread(os.path.join(dirname, imagefile))
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(args.output_dir, imagefile), im)
```

Because `imwrite()` needs to receive a filename parameter, I changed `find_all_files` to return a tuple, so you can use the same filename for the output, and choose which directory name you add in front.

Rewriting the images seems like a very inefficient way to do this, though. Why don't you simply copy the files?

Answer (score 1):

`find_all_files` is a generator. The variable `folder_img` will be bound to that generator. Calling `cv2.imread()` on that generator is not going to work because `imread()` expects an image file, not a generator.

You need to *iterate* over the generator to copy each file one by one. Something like this:

```
folder_img = find_all_files(args.input_dir)
for filename in find_all_files(args.input_dir):
    im = cv2.imread(filename)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(args.output_dir, os.path.basename(filename)), im)
```

Note also that `args.output_dir` is a string that represents the desination directory name. You need to specify the path of the file including the directory. Use `os.path.join()` and `os.path.basename()` to do that.

If all you are wanting to do is to copy the files from one directory to another then you should perhaps use [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) as there is no point in opening the image files and then writing them back out. Also, your `find_all_files()` generator function will pass back all files, including directories, so you need to add some logic to detect image files and filter out those that are unwanted.